# How to fill first sequence with elements of second sequence

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have two sequences, first sequence larger or have same size as the second.

For example for `val first = 1 to 7` and `val second = Seq(3, 5)`. I want to generate a sequence that looks like this:

```
first |second| result
    1 |      |   3  
    2 |      |   3
    3 |   3  |   3
    4 |      |   3
    5 |   5  |   5
    6 |      |   5
    7 |      |   5
```

Second example:

```
val first = 1 to 7
val second = Seq(3, 5, 6)

result will be Seq(3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6)
```

I am looking for a general solution.

Comment: Can the second Seq be the longer one? Can min(second) < min(first) or max(snd) > max(first) or will there always be less values in second, and always in the range of the Range? Is it always a range, or could it be (1,2,3, 6, 7, 8) and the snd be (3,5), with 5 not finding a matching partner? Is there an easy to understand real world scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straightforward, oneliner solution. Create the sequence of the first element of the second list and all elements of the second list smaller than currently mapped element of the first list and take the greatest element of this sequence.

```
val first = 1 to 7
val second = List(3, 5, 6)

val result = (first.map(x => (second.head +: second.filter(_ <= x)).last))
```

Comment: This is a nice solution in terms of brevity and readability, but OP should be careful if their input data is large, as this solution is less efficient compared to the others.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way:

```
scala> val first = 1 to 7 toList
first: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

scala> val second = List(3,5)
second: List[Int] = List(3, 5)

scala> val result = first.map(x => if(x < second.tail.head) second.head else second.tail.head)
result: List[Int] = List(3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5)
```

However, this is not very flexible but it satisfies your question.

Comment: thx. But I really looking for general scenario, your code will not work if second will be `List(3,5,6)`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself. Given sequences in a question

```
first.foldLeft((second, Seq.empty[Int])) { case ((sec, acc), f) =>
    if (sec.tail.isEmpty) (sec, sec.head +: acc)
    else if (f >= sec.tail.head) (sec.tail, sec.tail.head +: acc)
    else (sec, sec.head +: acc)
}._2.reverse
```

provides correct result

Answer (score 1):

Recursive solution using `span`

```
@annotation.tailrec
def recurse(first: Seq[Int], second: Seq[Int], acc: Seq[Int] = List.empty): Seq[Int] = {
  second match {
    case a :: b :: tail =>
      val (f1, f2) = first.span(_ != b)
      recurse(f2, b :: tail, List.fill(f1.length)(a) ++ acc)
    case a :: Nil =>
      (List.fill(first.length)(a) ++ acc).reverse
  }
}

val first = 1 to 7

println(recurse(first, Seq(3, 5)))
// List(3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5)

println(recurse(first, Seq(3, 5, 6)))
// List(3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6)
```